# MFMailComposeViewController memory management

Tags: ios, memory-management, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I created an app in which the user uses the front camera to take pictures and emails them, and the app never goes into background for at least 8 hours; the app is displayed in an office and must be always in foreground. Everything happens in an UIViewController.

The issue is with the MFMailComposeViewController, specifically with the memory which it consumes. In Instruments - Activity Monitor there is a MailCompositionS which keeps increasing in real memory usage.

My code is:

```
- (void)emailPhoto
{
    NSString *emailTitle;
    NSString *messageBody;

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];

    NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoView.image, 0.4);
    [mc addAttachmentData:dataImage mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"image.jpg"];

    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];

    mc = nil;
    dataImage = nil;
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        [self backToCamera];
    }];
}
```

I really don't understand what could be the problem. With or without the image attachment the MailCompositionS keeps increasing in memory consumption, and because the app always stays in that UIViewController and never goes into background, the memory is never released.

PS I am not detecting any leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a once instance of `MFMailComposeViewController` in a property. instead of creating an instance for each Photo. just copy the couples of lines. 
`self.mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];` 
`mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;` in 
`viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()`.

Good Luck

Comment: I need to use the MFMailComposeViewController multiple times, if i alloc init in viewDidLoad the second time i need to send an email will not work.